# iOS whatsapp offline pending messages not supported

Tags: messages

I'd like to know if there is a way to press the whatsapp "send" button while I'm offline (for instance on the metro) so they are send latter when rich connection.
This can be done on the Android version and is a useful feature. There is a way to do it on the iOS version? If not do you know if there is any intention to implement this feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Here in iOS that's not currently possible**, in fact when you've no connection and try to send a message, the **Send** button will be **disabled**, and even though you could successfully tap it before the connection goes off, the message wouldn't get sent and a red icon would appear on its right side, to alert you it was not sent and it won't until you don't get connection back.

---

## Summary

So the only **messages** which will be **sent** when you get the **connection back** will be those who were **sent** when you had actually a **connection**, but got **lost** during the process of sending the message.

Instead you **won't** be able to do that when you have **no connection** at all.

---

Though, developers love to hear their customers **feedback**, so I highly suggest you to give it a try and contact WhatsApp support (**support@whatsapp.com**) for iOS and let them know your idea, who knows it may be added in the next update hopefully!

Hope this helped you out!

Comment: Nice answer. Do you think that's due to background-app-usage restrictions in iOS? Could Whatsapp theoretically get around this and enable background sending?

Comment: Yes I think anything you can think of is possible. The fact this is already possible In Android and not in iOS makes me surely think there's something in between these two Operating Systems. I think you may try to contact WhatsApp support and tell them your suggestion, or maybe (if you have the right version of iOS) see if this is possible using the jailbreak, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Well Android and iOS are very different in how they handle background apps. In iOS, for an app to be kept open in the background, it must actively be using Notification Services, be connected to a Bluetooth device, be on a VoIP call, or be actively calculating something (like factors of a number). Additionally, it can request to have 3 minutes in the background at a random time the system determines. On Android, it is much easier to keep an app open in the background as there aren't many such restrictions. So yeah, the operating systems are actually pretty different in this regard!

Comment: Yeap, definitely agree @JohnRamos

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: This is now supported (starting from version 2.17.1) on iOS.